# Can "presence_query" be used in the new slack app?

Tags: slack-api

- I want to query the presence of users in a Slack workspace.
- Using the old (classic) app, I can do it using [presence_query](https://api.slack.com/events/presence_query) via Slack RTM.
- However, RTM requires depracted bot scopes (and the old classic app).

Can I use (and how) presence_query with the new slack app (I'm using python)?

This is my current implementation (using the old classic app):

```py
from slack_sdk.rtm_v2 import RTMClient

rtm_client = RTMClient(token='SLACK_BOT_TOKEN')

@rtm_client.on("presence_change")
def receive_presence_changes(client:RTMClient, event:dict):
    print(event)

rtm_client.connect()
rtm_client.send(
    payload={
        "type" : "presence_query",
        'ids'  : ids_list,
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are currently no ways to subscribe to presence-oriented events on the Events API or via Socket Mode. The legacy RTM API is the only avenue still available.